# How to scale an object so that all it's faces are moved 2 centimeters towards the median from their original position?

Tags: mesh, transforms, normals

I have modelled the outside of an airplane's fuselage in Blender, and now I want to model the inside and doors. For that, I need to make the fuselage skin a 2 centimeter's wide "wall". Below is a screenshot of that "skin":
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3jIl.png]
Now, I need to move each face inwards along it's normal by 2 cm and scale it at the same time so that all faces still fit together.

I've tried various things:

1. Simple scale
2. Push - Pull
3. Shrink - Fatten
   all with more or less the same result - in some places the outer and inner faces were spaced 10 cm and in others only millimeters.

I could of course move all the vertices by hand, then connect them - but that would take ages. Isn't there a simpler method ? Basically I need to implode the skin by 2 cm.

Comment: Shrink/Fatten should work but you need to apply the scale before

Comment: @moonboots ah, will try that !

Comment: @moonboots wow … This worked, thank you sooooooo much ! If you make it an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote it ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of your object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) before you do the *Shrink/Fatten*.